# Digital Persona one touch sdk- cannot perform verification in java

Tags: java, fingerprint

I've captured a featureset in the form of a string using an applet. I need to convert that string back into bytes and deserialize it in order to match it. But I dont know where am going wrong as its not comparing the template with the featureset.
I've been fighting with this for weeks, Please anyone help me.

```
//Converting string stored in db back to template:
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[1];
            byteArray = hexStringToByteArray(dbTemplate);
            DPFPTemplate template = DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory().createTemplate();
            template.deserialize(byteArray);

//Converting featureset string captured by applet 
            byte[] fsArray = new byte[1];
            fsArray = hexStringToByteArray(ftsetstring);
            DPFPFeatureSet features = null;
            features.deserialize(fsArray);

//Comparing template with features acquired
            DPFPVerification matcher =   DPFPGlobal.getVerificationFactory().createVerification();
            DPFPVerificationResult fresult = matcher.verify(features, template);

                if (fresult.isVerified()) {

                    return "The fingerprint was VERIFIED.";

                } else {
                    return "The fingerprint was NOT VERIFIED.";
```

Where is my error???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used Digital Persona before, but in any API, this:

```
        DPFPFeatureSet features = null;
        features.deserialize(fsArray);
```

Will cause a `NullPointerException`. I tried to look up how to correctly use the class but you have to be a member of Digital Persona to see the javadoc. Sorry!

Comment: Thanks, yes it gave a null pointer exception. 
I finally managed to figured out the correct class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a capturer with data listener to get the features from the fingerprint device:

```
DPFPCapture capturer=DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();
capturer.addDataListener(new DPFPDataListener(){
    public void dataAcquired(DPFPDataEvent e){
        DPFPSample sample=e.getSample();
        DPFPFeatureSet features=extractor.createFeatureSet(sample, DPFPDataPurpose.DATA_PURPOSE_ENROLLMENT);
        // Serialize or verify features
    }
});
```

If you're serializing:

```
DPFPEnrollment enroller=DPFPGlobal.getEnrollmentFactory().createEnrollment();
enroller.addFeatures(features);
if(enroller.getFeaturesNeeded()==0){
    byte[] result=enroller.getTemplate().serialize();
    // Save result in data base
}
```

If you're verifying:

```
// Get byte[] result from data base
DPFPTemplateFactory templateFactory=DPFPGlobal.getTemplateFactory();
DPFPVerificationResult verificator=verificator.verify(features, templateFactory.createTemplate(result));
if(verificator.isVerified()){
    // Grant access
}
```